# How to key press "Arrow down/ Enter" key in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh, expect

I want to automate .sh installation.
So, I have to key press 'Arrow down' key for selection and press 'Enter'.

```
./install.sh
expect "Welcome"
send "{down}"
expect "install"
send "Enter"
```

Comment: Why not updating the installation script to eliminate unnecessary user interactions?

Comment: This is where `autoexpect` can help -- read its man page

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Linux, you can use `xdotool` to simulate keystrokes:

```sh
# To press the down arrow key
$ xdotool key Down

# To press the Enter key
$ xdotool key Return
```